# Multipart Form Data with primitive type data along with file in retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipartform-data, rx-java2

[image]

The above request has values type of String, Boolean, Int and an image attachment which is done using multipart.

```
 val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

I've also added Scalar converters to the request and my API is

```
@Multipart
@POST(AppConstants.Network.CREATE_STORE)
fun createStore(
   @Header("Authorization") token: String,

   //Step 1
   @Part imagePath: MultipartBody.Part?,
   @Part("Name") storeName: RequestBody,
   @Part("StoreOwnerName") storeOwnerName: RequestBody,
   @Part("StoreOwnerGender") storeOwnerGender: RequestBody,
   @Part("StoreOwnerDob") storeOwnerDob: RequestBody,
   @Part("AddressLine1") addressLine1: RequestBody,
   @Part("AddressLine2") addressLine2: RequestBody,
   @Part("AddressLine3") addressLine3: RequestBody,
   @Part("Place") place: RequestBody,
   @Part("PinCode") pinCode: Int,
   @Part("ContactNumber") contactNumber: RequestBody,
   @Part("Email") email: RequestBody,

   //Step 2
   @Part("IsRegistered") isRegistered: Boolean,
   @Part("HasGst") hasGst: Boolean,
   @Part("GSTNumber") GSTNumber: Int,
   @Part("HasInsurance") hasInsurance: Boolean,
   @Part("HasBankAccount") hasBankAccount: Boolean,

   //Step 3
   @Part("StaffSize") staffSize: Int,
   @Part("StoreSize") storeSize: Int,
   @Part("RunningFrom") runningFromDate: RequestBody,
   @Part("StoreTypeId") storeTypeId: Int,
   @Part("AverageTurnOver") averageTurnOver: Int,
   // @Part("AverageCustomerVisit") averageCustomerVisit: String,

   //  @Part("HasStaff") hasStaff: Boolean,
   @Part("OwnerResponseId") ownerResponseId: Int,
   @Part("Remarks") remarks: RequestBody

   ): Single<ResponseBody>
```

My api definition is,

```
   apiService.createStore(
            "bearer ".plus(AppPreferences(context!!).token!!),
            storeName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            imagePath = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                "ImagePath",
                store.imagePathFile?.name!!,
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFilePath)
            ),
            storeOwnerName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            storeOwnerGender = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            storeOwnerDob = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            addressLine1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            addressLine2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            addressLine3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            place = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Fsafa"),
            pinCode = 642526,
            contactNumber = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "etet@gga.co"),
            isRegistered = false,
            hasGst = true,
            GSTNumber = 23423432,
            hasBankAccount = false,
            averageTurnOver = 345346,
            hasInsurance = false,
            staffSize = 546,
            ownerResponseId = 2,
            remarks = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            runningFromDate = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name"),
            storeSize = 324,
            storeTypeId = 2
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to add the Scalar Converter to retrofit so that the data which you sent will be correctly obtained at the back end.

```
Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

For sending primitive data in form data POST request you've to send it like this,

```
@Multipart
@POST(AppConstants.Network.CREATE_STORE)
fun createStore(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Part imagePath: MultipartBody.Part?,
    @Part("Name") storeName: String,
    @Part("StoreOwnerName") storeOwnerName: String,
    @Part("StoreOwnerGender") storeOwnerGender: String?,
    @Part("IsRegistered") isRegistered: Boolean?,
```

Calling the request by

```
apiService.createStore(
            token = "bearer ".plus(AppPreferences(context!!).token!!),
            imagePath = if (imageFilePath.isEmpty()) null else MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                "ImagePath",
                store.imagePathFile!!.name!!,
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), store.imagePathFile)
            storeName = store.name,
            storeOwnerName = store.storeOwnerName,
            storeOwnerGender = store.storeOwnerGender,
            isRegistered = store.isRegistered,
```